# Groovy list with variable name containing a dot (.) gets converted to string

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a list in groovy, defined as

```
env.list = ["abc","def"]
```

If I try using this in a for loop

```
for (letters in env.list) {
  print("Letter is $letters")
}
```

It will iterate over each letter and print the following -

```
Letter is [
Letter is "
Letter is a
.....
```

If I define the list as follows -

```
list = ["abc","def"]
```

It will treat this as a list. The for loop will print the following.

```
Letter is abc
Letter is def
```

Was using groovy to run my Jenkins pipeline.

1. Why is there a difference based on the name?
2. How can we define a list using a variable name with a dot (.)?

Comment: what is `env` ? does it have a `list` property ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in jenkins pipeline the `env` - is a variable that holds list of environment variables:

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-environment-variables

and environment variable could hold only a string

so when you try to assign to environment variable a list - it automatically converted to string

```
env.list = ["abc","def"]
```

equivalent to

```
env.list = ["abc","def"].toString()
```

and then you are iterating string by char...

Answer (score 0):

To explain *why* this behavior happens, it is best to turn to the Jenkins source code.

The global variable name is `env` which takes us to [`org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.EnvActionImpl.Binder`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/9b768a42f60cc3389031646c24927fa062d444e1/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/EnvActionImpl.java#L142-L158). This binds the value to the script, which in this case is the pipeline.

[Source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/9b768a42f60cc3389031646c24927fa062d444e1/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/EnvActionImpl.java#L146-L153):

```
    @Override public EnvActionImpl getValue(CpsScript script) throws Exception {
        Run<?,?> run = script.$build();
        if (run != null) {
            return EnvActionImpl.forRun(run);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("no associated build");
        }
    }
```

`EnvActionImpl` extends the Groovy type [`GroovyObjectSupport`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyObjectSupport.html) [(source code)](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/9b768a42f60cc3389031646c24927fa062d444e1/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/EnvActionImpl.java#L54). `GroovyObjectSupport` has this is in its documentation:

> A useful base class for Java objects wishing to be Groovy objects

So, this is Jenkins allowing a Java implementation to allow it to set it's behavior for Groovy. The methods you are using are [`public java.lang.Object getProperty(java.lang.String property)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyObjectSupport.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-) and [`public void setProperty(java.lang.String property, java.lang.Object newValue)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyObjectSupport.html#setProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-), so we will look closer at `EnvActionImpl`'s implementation of them.

For `setProperty`, the implementation is [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/9b768a42f60cc3389031646c24927fa062d444e1/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/EnvActionImpl.java#L98-L105):

```
@Override public void setProperty(String propertyName, Object newValue) {
    env.put(propertyName, String.valueOf(newValue));
    try {
        owner.save();
    } catch (IOException x) {
        throw new RuntimeException(x);
    }
}
```

Looking higher up in the class we see the declaration of `env` is [`private final Map<String,String> env;`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/9b768a42f60cc3389031646c24927fa062d444e1/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/EnvActionImpl.java#L59). The propery name is used as the key (`list` in your example) and the value is the `String.valueOf` return of `newValue`, which in your case is the stringified `["abc","def"]`.

Looking at [`setProperty`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/9b768a42f60cc3389031646c24927fa062d444e1/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/EnvActionImpl.java#L88-L96):

```
@Override public String getProperty(String propertyName) {
    try {
        CpsThread t = CpsThread.current();
        return EnvironmentExpander.getEffectiveEnvironment(getEnvironment(), t.getContextVariable(EnvVars.class), t.getContextVariable(EnvironmentExpander.class)).get(propertyName);
    } catch (Exception x) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, null, x);
        return null;
    }
}
```

That can be dove into more to understand the `EnvironmentExpander` and `CpsThread` mechanics, but the quickest way is to just check the signature - `public String`.

This explains what Jenkins is doing under the hood with the `env` variable in pipeline scripts, and why your iteration is happening over a `String`'s characters, and not the list like you might expect. If you created your own variable and tried it yourself, you would see the difference in behavior between, for example `Map` and the `EnvActionImpl` type.

```
final myVar = [:]
myVar.list = ["abc","def"]
env.list = ["abc","def"]
echo "${myVar.list.getClass()}"
echo "${env.list.getClass()}"
```