# getClass() return different class depends on variable declared as def or env

Tags: groovy

why in groovy there is a difference between these two variables?

```
def x = ["one":["D7D7D7", "D2D2D2"]]
env.y = ["two":["D7D7D7", "D2D2D2"]]

x.getClass() -> returns java.util.LinkedHashMap
y.getClass() -> returns java.lang.String
```

and I need variable to be env and HashMap :)

Comment: if your question is about jenkins-pipeline - then thet's your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52505880/groovy-list-with-variable-name-containing-a-dot-gets-converted-to-string/52506452#52506452

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't inform us about your environment (SoapUi, jenkins, grails, whatever)  or what env actually is there is really no way to answer your question with proper precision.

With that being said, for an example of how you can end up with the behavior in your code, in groovy tings like the following are possible:

```
class Env { 
  private String val

  String getY() {
    val
  }

  void setY(String val) {
    this.val = val
  }
}

def env = new Env()

def x = ["one":["D7D7D7", "D2D2D2"]]
env.y = ["two":["D7D7D7", "D2D2D2"]]

env.with { 
  println(x.getClass()) // -> returns java.util.LinkedHashMap
  println(y.getClass()) // -> returns java.lang.String
}
```

where from this code we can immediately see that the property `y` (in groovy represented as the `getY` and `setY` methods and accessed directly using `env.y` and `env.y = ...`) is of type `String` and the hashmap is automatically converted to a string on the line `env.y = ["two":["D7D7D7", "D2D2D2"]]` since the variable we are assigning to is of type `String`.

This is an example of one mechanism which could make code like yours return the values it does. Like mentioned above, you do not provide enough information to give a more complete answer without making qualified guesses as to what context you are executing your code in.